# Using curl_init in Zend Application is causing Session Error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm getting this weird error in my Zend application with this piece of code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.xyz.com/ab.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);      

if (!isset($location->country)) {
$location = new Zend_Session_Namespace('location');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$location->city=$xml->City;
}
```

This is the error, I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()
```

When I remove that code everything works fine.
Any idea ??

Edit: On further debugging I found that the error was not because of the curl code - it was ocuring later when I was assigning $location->city=$xml->City;
But when I change that line to $location->city=''.$xml->City.'';
It starts working..........this is driving me crazy !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what your issue is, but I can tell you that Zend_Http_Client is very nice and robust and it has support for multiple adapters including CURL.

Example:

```
$http = new Zend_Http_Client(
  'url',
   $this->options
);
$response = $http->request();
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `new Zend_Session_Namespace('location');` call will try to start a new session but apparently one has already been started without using Zend_Session calls, and thus it throws an exception. So check the rest of your code (and php.ini) to find out where you start that session (it could be because session.auto_start=1 in php.ini, or a session_start() call somewhere) and fix it as you see fit...

Comment: Thanks for your reponse - Thats what I thought and my search on google also led me to same conclusion - but see my edit section above - when I make that change  everything starts working fine - It seems weird to me as to what the connection is